# Explanation of Object creation with reduce

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm unclear as to how the reduce function is able to create an object from an array like this example especially the line:

```
p[c[0]] = c[1];
```

is this an odd syntax for creating a key value pair I just haven't seen before?
Be grateful for any help
the code is as below
...

```
var array = [ [1,'a'], [2,'b'], [3,'c'] ]; 

function objectify(array) {
  return array.reduce((p, c) => {
       p[c[0]] = c[1];
       return p;
  }, {});
}
console.log(objectify(array))
```

Comment: Could you please explain a little more about what's not clear? Walk us through how you think the code works and then point out anything confusing

Comment: FYI, you can simplify this greatly with `console.log(Object.fromEntries(array))`

Answer (score 0):

```
Array.reduce(function(accumulator, currentValue){
   // currentValue is the individual element in array pass to this function one by one
}, default_value_of_accumulator);
```

Imagine the reduce function loop through the array elements one by one and pass the element into callback function as currentValue and together with an accumulator, in your case default to empty {}. In each run of callback function per array element, the callback function modifies the accumulator to your wish ( add new property to object ).  Consider your case and the each run of callback function as follow.

```
1st run:
(p, c) => {
    /*  
        before - 
        p= {} // empty default value as you pass to the reduce function
        c= [1,'a'] // first element of array
    */
    p[c[0]] = c[1]; 
    /*
       after -
       p = { 1: 'a' }
    */
    return p;

}, {})

2sn run:
(p, c) => {
    /*  
        before - 
        p= { 1: 'a'} // previous result of accumulator
        c= [2,'b'] // second element of array
    */
    p[c[0]] = c[1]; 
    /*
       after -
       p = { 1: 'a', 2: 'b' }
    */
    return p;

}, {})

3rd run:
(p, c) => {
    /*  
        before - 
        p= { 1: 'a', 2: 'b' } // previous result of accumulator
        c= [3,'c'] // last element of array
    */
    p[c[0]] = c[1]; 
    /*
       after (final result of reduce) -
       p = { 1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c' }
    */
    return p;

}, {})
```